# Create skeleton data using depth files

Tags: kinect, openni, kinect-sdk

I have a bunch of jpeg and depth(raw) files saved on disk using kinect sdk
Is there a way  to create the skeleton data (joint points)  using these files with openni? 
If so how it could be done? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenNI does not handle the skeleton tracking.  Rather it is done through the NITE middleware layer that plugs into OpenNI.  NITE, and the algorithms that handle the skeleton generation, are closed source and not available to dissection.

I am not aware of an API call to push a raw image into the skeleton process for pulling out the skeleton data.  I'd bet that movement within the stream actually plays a part in the algorithm, making single image processing very imprecise.